# How to add condition in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need a mongoose query, to select only one record in or condition. There is a collection of blogs. Some of them are in English or in French. Certain blogs are a duplicate like they have the same content but in a different language.But they have same 'group_id'.

If I filter blogs based on some criteria, like 'category' only blogs with the 'userLanguage' should show. But if there is no, show the other language. How do I generate a mongoose query for this?

```
db.find($and:[{category:'Health'},{$or: [{language: 'en'},{language:'fr'}]}])
```

But it gives 2 records if both 'en' and 'fr' is present, I need only either 'en' or 'fr'. How can I implement this in one query ?

These are some sample documents,

```
"{_id: '1', category_id: 'xyz', language:'en', group_id: 'aaa'} ", 
"{_id: '2', category_id: 'xyz', language:'fr', group_id: 'aaa'}",
"{_id: '3', category_id: 'xyz' language: 'en', group_id: 'bbb'}",
"{_id: '4', category_id: 'xyz', language: 'fr', group_id: 'ccc'}"
```

I request for category_id : 'xyz' and language: 'en'. So the result should be,

```
"{_id: '1', category_id: 'xyz', language:'en', group_id: 'aaa'} ", 
"{_id: '3', category_id: 'xyz' language: 'en', group_id: 'bbb'}",
"{_id: '4', category_id: 'xyz', language: 'fr', group_id: 'ccc'}"
```

I have an array of distinct group_id = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']. So the condition is like,

```
group_id: $in:group_id $$ language  should be 'en' if not 'fr'
```

Comment: If I'm reading it right then the "same" articles need to be "grouped" together using `.aggregate()`, where you would push the content for each language into an array. Then you need to `$filter` the array content for either the selected language or the default. So it's not just a "query", but "manipulation" on the server. We would need document samples to be able to walk you through it.

Comment: you don't need the first "and" in your query since every first level property of the query object are already linked by an "and" by the mongo engine

Comment: I have added some data, please check it.

Answer (score -1):

Use findOne query, which gives you only one result, like this

```
db.findOne($and:[{category:'Health'},{$or: [{language: 'en'},{language:'fr'}]}]);
```

Comment: But I have priority in language, if user language is English, select 'en' , suppose that is not present select 'fr'.

Comment: THen, I would suggest u to write a simple logic around ur query which returns two records.